# Add to array if set

Tags: php, arrays, isset

Is there a better/shorter way to do this?

Each variable is a MySQL table value that is called. I have a main table and an override table, so call the first table, extract the resulting array, then call the override table and extract those results to override the first extract.

```
if (isset($Price1)){
    $AllPrices[] = $Price1;}
if (isset($Price2)){
    $AllPrices[] = $Price2;}
if (isset($Price3)){
    $AllPrices[] = $Price3;}    
if (isset($Price4)){
    $AllPrices[] = $Price4;}
if (isset($SPrice1)){
    $AllPrices[] = $SPrice1;}
if (isset($SPrice2)){
    $AllPrices[] = $SPrice2;}
if (isset($SPrice3)){
    $AllPrices[] = $SPrice3;}
```

Comment: "All variables are pulling from MySQL" what does this mean? That is, how are these variables being set specifically?

Comment: Not really, it looks like you need to check each individual variable, which you're doing.  Unless those vars were originally in an array or something...

Comment: can you show us the full code (the part that pulls from the DB and loops for example)?

Comment: There is a way using variable variables, but I don't recommend it.  Best would be to originate all those vars like `$Price1` as array keys rather than global vars.

Comment: Each variable is a table value that is called. I have a main table and an override table, so call the first able, extract, the values, then call the override and extract those values to override. Then I run the code above.

Answer (score 4):

I've done things like this in the past, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
$variables = array("Price1", "Price2", "Price3", "Price4", "SPrice1", "SPrice2", "SPrice3");

$AllPrices = array();

foreach ($variables as $variable)
{
    if (isset($$variable))
        $AllPrices[] = $$variable;
}
```

See [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more information on how the `$$` syntax works in PHP.

But I do agree with the comments to your post... You really should take another look at how you're getting this data. This solution is not ideal in the least.

Comment: I think it is a neat solution for the information you got from the question :-)

Comment: Doesn't work for what I am doing (see my last comment), but nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++){
    $current = ${'AllPrices'.$i};
    isset($current) && array_push($AllPrices, $current);
}
```

As also posted in above answer, using array of variable names is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**This structure is not recommended.**

Instead of using `$price1, $price2, ...` **use an array** - `$price[1], $price[2], ...` (Do the same for $SPrice).

**Then you could use a simple `array_merge`:**

```
$AllPrices = array_merge($price, $SPrice);
```